# Javascript wrongly decodes unicode

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to get an id of a font-awesome icon. It is located in `::before` style. When i use

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("[id='5']"), '::before').getPropertyValue('content')
```

to get it, instead of `"\f458"`, `"\"\""` is returned.

I assume that JavaScript is trying to convert the code into a char but fails. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: f458 you say? look at the numbers in the little box - it's f458 - looks like success

Comment: @Bravo as you pointed out, there are those numbers, but any attempt to get them directly, not just a box with numbers has failed.

Comment: what's your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decoding works, the problem is the [**font**](https://utf8-icons.com/utf-8-character-62552). If there's no match for this character in a font you use, it'll be mangled or in the form of the unicode value in a box.

Since it's in [the private area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas), depending on the font it might be resolved into a glyph or be mangled or be just empty/space.

Checking in the [Font Awesome Cheatsheet](https://origin.fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free) it looks like a an icon for [`quidditch`](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/quidditch?style=solid).

Perhaps there's a text to image/svg map somewhere on the internet (and if not, then just copy-paste localy and create one) which you might use if the font itself isn't good or you are decoding in a problematic environment (can't install fonts, etc).

Comment: I figured out how to get `"\\u0022\\uf458\\u0022"`. Is there any way to get the middle `\\uf458` as plain string?

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help. Will accept your answer as soon as i can :)